Inconsistent behavior found in the traefik ingress logs
I found some strange log entries and I am trying to find out what it means.
99.9999 % of the log entries follow this format:
x.x.x.x - - [07/Apr/2024:15:08:55 +0000] "GET /modules/theripper-premium-hub/scripts/module.js HTTP/2.0" 304 0 "-" "-" 219755 "fvtt-<USERNAME>-16b67515c53b284c7d5f@kubernetescrd" "http://10.244.13.44:30000" 41ms

Then I get these entries.
x.x.x.x - - [07/Apr/2024:14:59:40 +0000] "GET /icons/weapons/hammers/hammer-drilling-spiked.webp HTTP/2.0" 304 0 "-" "-" 233358 "websecure-fvtt-<USERNAME>-<USERNAME>-server-com@kubernetes" "http://10.244.8.65:30000" 2ms

I am having random performance issues and I trying to track down the smoking gun. This logging difference worries me as I am wondering if traefik is dealing with some requests differently and causing my performance issues with some customers.
fvtt -> kubernetes namespace
username -> name of the statefullset pod
server.com -> domain name found in the ssl configuration
websecure -> name of the entrypoint in traefik.
Thank you for taking a look.
Brad

Traefik was getting confused with an ingress and ingress route. I was transitioning from ingress to ingress routes and had some leftover ingress manifests for the same statefulset.  Once the ingress was removed the logs no longer showed the different entries.
